# Painting a line between a list of children in different positions (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, graphics

I would like to achieve a result where I have a list of widgets in different positions on the screen, and a line pointing from the center of the widget above to the center of the widget below. It's a little hard to explain, I've attached some images of the result I'm looking for.

Currently what I have
[Current Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TuoG.png)

Sketch of what I'm looking for:
[Rough sketch of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jpoa.png)

I tried using a CustomPainter but the lines would only appear vertically.

```dart
class ConnectedColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final Color lineColor;
  final double lineWidth;

  ConnectedColumn({super.key,
    required this.children,
    this.lineColor = Colors.black,
    this.lineWidth = 2.0,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> connectedChildren = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length - 1; i++) {
      connectedChildren.add(children[i]);
      connectedChildren.add(
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(50, 50), // Adjust the size as needed
            painter: LinePainter(
              start: Offset(0, 0),  // Start at the top
              end: Offset(0, 50),   // End at the bottom
              color: lineColor,
              strokeWidth: lineWidth,
            ),
          )
      );
    }

    // Add the last child
    connectedChildren.add(children.last);

    return Column(
      children: connectedChildren,
    );
  }
}

class LineConnector extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child1;
  final Widget child2;

  LineConnector({required this.child1, required this.child2});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: Size(100, 100), // Set the size according to your requirements
      painter: LinePainter(
        start: Offset(0, 50), // Adjust the start and end offsets as needed
        end: Offset(100, 50),
        color: Colors.blue,  // You can specify the color and other properties here
        strokeWidth: 2.0,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(child: child1, left: 0, top: 0),
          Positioned(child: child2, right: 0, top: 0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset start, end;
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;

  LinePainter({required this.start, required this.end, this.color = Colors.black, this.strokeWidth = 2.0});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    canvas.drawLine(start, end, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I've been using Padding's to position my widgets from the center, maybe that might be a problem? Not too sure.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).